# PHP framework for a Line-of-Business application? (Lots of CRUD)

Tags: php, frameworks, crud, lob

I'm on the way to port an old Java Swing-based application to PHP, and this application is very CRUD-intensive, with lots of tables and reports.

Application must be written in PHP (server already exists), and must be secure (no SQL injection or cross site scripting, etc).

And, I'm not an expert with PHP. Some years ago I wrote some simple websites, but I mainly develop desktop applications (Delphi, Java Swing or VB.NET).

So, which PHP framework can I use? Exists anyone that simplifies CRUD and reporting operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`Symfony's`](http://www.symfony-project.org/) [`Admin Generator`](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/14-Admin-Generator) is great if you have lots of CRUD.

Comment: Ok. And which is better, Symfony 1.4 o Symfony 2?

Comment: If you're starting a new project and you've never used Symfony before, I can't see any reason to go with the older verison.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/). It has many similarities with Java and .NET world and you would feel at-home and in a pleasant object-oriented environment. It manages CRUDs perfectly without any "generation".